# SQL compare value 3 records

Tags: ms-access

I'm strugling to build a query in MS Access for following question I received:

> Can you compare the last 3 periods and if the quantity is 3 times the
>   same, show that record

The table has following fields:

1. Plant (text)
2. StorageLocation (text)
3. Material (text)
4. Period (text)
5. Quantity (number)

Example:

```
Plant - Sloc - Mat - Period - Quant

0310 - 0100 - 4040 - 003.2016 - 135

0310 - 0100 - 4040 - 004.2016 - 135

0310 - 0100 - 4040 - 005.2016 - 135

0310 - 0160 - 4040 - 003.2016 - 897

0310 - 0160 - 4040 - 004.2016 - 897

0310 - 0300 - 4040 - 003.2016 - 451

0310 - 0300 - 4040 - 004.2016 - 579

0310 - 0300 - 4040 - 005.2016 - 693

.......................
```

Based on the example above I expect in the query 1 row

```
Plant - Sloc - Mat - Quant

0310 - 0100 - 4040 - 135
```

Retrieving the last 3 periods I got via criteria

`In (SELECT TOP 3 tbl_SiteStock.FiscalPeriodYear)` on the field FiscalPeriodYear

But how do I have to build the query in order to compare with the previous periods ?

Any answers or suggestions are welcome.

Jan

Comment: Why the ms Access Tag?

Comment: Is it MySQL, SQL Server or MS Access ? You specify MySQL but this is not valid MySQL syntax  `SELECT TOP 3  `

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: @ Jens, because it is a query in MS Access
@ Thomas G and Strawberry, I removed MySQL tag as this was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a conditional aggregate query:

```sql
SELECT tbl_SiteStock.Plant, tbl_SiteStock.Sloc, tbl_SiteStock.Mat, tbl_SiteStock.Quant
FROM tbl_SiteStock
WHERE tbl_SiteStock.Period IN ('003.2016', '004.2016', '005.2016')
GROUP BY tbl_SiteStock.Plant, tbl_SiteStock.Sloc, tbl_SiteStock.Mat, tbl_SiteStock.Quant
HAVING Count(*) = 3;
```

Comment: @ Parfait: This is a good suggestion. The only thing I need to change is that the IN ('003.2016','004.2016','005.2016') can't be fixed because it will change monthly. But I can solve that. Thanks for support !

Comment: Ok. Please accept solution to confirm resolution. Yes, pass values dynamically as parameters or re-build query at runtime. Do note such values are not datetime fields.